# ModuleNotFoundError in Anaconda3 when installing package with pip

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running conda 4.4.8 on mac OS 10.11.16 and I'm trying to properly install a third-party package that I have as a tar.gz file. The package installation seems to work without any issue (having already tried to install, this in what I get when I run it again):

> $: pip install ~/Downloads/pydelay-0.1.1.tar.gz
>
> Processing ~/Downloads/pydelay-0.1.1.tar.gz
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pydelay==0.1.1 from file://~/Downloads/pydelay-0.1.1.tar.gz in ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>   Building wheels for collected packages: pydelay
>   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pydelay ... done
>     Stored in directory: ~/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/5d/b7/4e/3896677f80cccebfc2d300904aca54ebbd6b0885cb9440e13d
>   Successfully built pydelay

Then I do a check to make sure there aren't dependencies missing:

> $: pip check pydelay
>
> No broken requirements found.

However, when I run my piece of code that uses the package, I get the following error:

> runfile('~/.../DDEin3+1D.py', wdir='~/...')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "ipython-input-16-12e8207a0dca", line 1, in 
>     runfile('~/.../DDEin3+1D.py', wdir='~/...')
>
> File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
>      execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
>     exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "~/.../DDEin3+1D.py", line 18, in 
>   from pydelay import dde23
>
> File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydelay/__init__.py", line 9, in 
>     from _dde23 import dde23
>
> **ModuleNotFoundError**: No module named '_dde23'

I don't *think* its a version problem, but because [the pydelay package is from 2009](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.1633.pdf) it very well could be.

Any help with getting the spyder editor (or command line python) to find this package would be greatly appreciated!

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[anaconda3](/questions/tagged/anaconda3)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone runs into something like this, I thought I would post the solution. In this instance, the __init__.py file was searching my default PATH for _dde23, which was actually located in the same directory as __init__.py. The solution was simply to change the import call in __init__.py to

> from ._dde23 import dde23

This told the file to look within the same directory for the module. I found similar problems throughout the package, and with this small change solved them all. I'm not an expert, but it might have been something to do with **pydelay** being built with python2.x while I was running python3.x.

Of course, getting other parts of this module to work with depreciated dependencies is another matter ;)